# calling Java soap webservice with rails -wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, soap, arguments

I am trying to call a java soap webservice within my ruby on rails app. Therefor I use the following code:

```
email = "awesome@tedmosbyisajerk.com"
pw = "legendary"
XSD::Charset.encoding = 'UTF8'
wsdlfile = "http://134.60.60.40:8080/FuturecanteenWebservice/DatabaseWSService?wsdl"
driver = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(wsdlfile).create_rpc_driver
driver.connectDB
@result = driver.checkUserForLogin(email, pw)
```

but when I run the action above I am always getting wrong number of arguments for any kind of method of the webservice I try to use.

Can anybody help me with this one?

Cheers for any help.

Answer (score 2):

First off, Ruby's SOAP is just terrible.  It is slightly better if you use the gem version of soap4r, but still just awful.

What does the WSDL look like for the checkUserForLogin method.  Are the arguments named? (if so, specify them like checkUserForLogin(:email => email, :pw => pw) )